# Is get a middleware in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I was reading about the middleware in express and how they work. I read that "use" is a middleware which has access to req object ,res object and the next middleware. "use" middleware uses the next middleware to pass the execution control to the next middleware. So now I am confused that whether get, post, delete and put are all middleware or not?

Comment: They are not middleware, please read the docs: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

Comment: @SuleymanSah https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router

Comment: @DaveNewton ops my mistake :) thank you for pointing this

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but the callback is a middleware. It can be thought of as middleware that handle only a specific HTTP verb.

Basically, a middleware is a function that takes three arguments, a request object, a response object, and a next function. They are a way to encapsulate functionality that operates on HTTP requests.

They are executed in a pipeline. If you call `next()`, the next middleware in the pipeline is called.

```
app.get('/path', function(req, res, next) { //---> that's the middleware (note the next)
  next() -> move on to next middleware in the pipeline
})
```

`app.use` [adds a middleware to the pipeline](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use).

> Mounts the specified middleware function or functions at the specified
>   path: the middleware function is executed when the base of the
>   requested path matches path.
>
> path: The path for which the **middleware function** is invoked;
>   callback: Callback functions; can be:
>
> - A **middleware function**.
> - A series of middleware functions (separated by commas).
> - An array of middleware functions.
> - A combination of all of the above.

Comment: It's *explicitly* middleware, it's just verb-specialized.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, middleware that handle only a specific HTTP verb.

Comment: That's what I said. I'm picking nits because it *is* "exactly" middleware; there's zero ambiguity.

Comment: But to me, the middleware is actually what's passed to `app.use`. `app.use` adds a middleware to the pipeline. That's why people think app.use is a middleware, well sort of, it adds a middleware. What do you think?

Comment: @DaveNewton app.use: Mounts the specified middleware function or functions at the specified path: the middleware function is executed when the base of the requested path matches path.

Comment: @DaveNewton to nitpick :)

Comment: `app.use` mounts middleware, as you state. `app.VERB` also mounts middleware specific to VERB. See [Router-level middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) for details, but the bottom line is that verb handlers are still just middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Verb handlers are a middleware sub-stack:

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router

> Router-level middleware works in the same way as application-level middleware, except it is bound to an instance of express.Router().

A specific example from that link:

```
// a middleware sub-stack that handles GET requests to the /user/:id path
router.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  // Etc.
}
```

Verb middleware doesn't always look like "generic" middleware because it's often the end of a middleware chain, but ultimately it's the same thing.

Contrast typical verb handlers with middleware executed for every request:

```
// a middleware function with no mount path. This code is executed for every request to the router
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now())
  next()
})
```

Think of middleware as an "interceptor", with verb middlewares as a somewhat pathological case in that they very often just ignore `next` since they're typically responsible for sending the response and nothing else–but they *can* still continue processing.